# How can I solve and plot a specific equation with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, graph

I am new to python and I have two questions that I really appreciate if you can help me to solve them.

1) How can I plot all the points (x, y) which satisfy the following equation?

y==11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))

Where x>0 and y>0.

2) Consider the following inequality where again x>0 and y >0:

```
y>11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))
```

I want to figure out range of y that satisfies the inequality given a specific x.

I used Mathematica before and I already have some ideas about the answers but I want to see how can I write appropriate codes in python (preferably by using pandas library) to solve the questions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to use `pandas` for plotting or storing solutions, I do not see how it fits this application.

For plotting, you have many options in Python. You can use [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/). It is a common plotting tool, straightforward, and several other plotting packages wrap it (e.g. `pandas` and `seaborn`).

Unlike Mathematica, Python is not specifically designed to perform symbolic math. There are some packages like [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), but they are not as featureful or powerful as Mathematica.